# detect the motion of the device in vehicle in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a requirement like the motion of the device in vehicle while driving should be detected when the application is in background. When the motion is detected the app should start automatically and move to foreground from background in iOS 7. I read that it is possible using CMMotionActivity Manager but have no exact clue to implement this functionality.

Comment: Is this possible using CMMotionActivity Manager